# All possible operations with two operators(+, -) on items of an array

Tags: ruby, math, permutation

Given an array, I want to generate a new array that contains the result of adding +1 or -1 to each item of the original array, in turn.  This is difficult to explain in words, so please see the example below.

For example, given the array

```
ary = [1,2]
```

The resulting array when adding or subtracting `1` from one item at a time should be:

```
[[1+1, 2], [1-1, 2], [1, 2+1], [1, 2-1]]
```

Similarly, resulting array when adding or subtracting `1` from two item at a time would be:

```
[[1+1, 2+1], [1+1, 2-1], [1-1, 2-1], [1-1, 2+1]]
```

Basically all possible outcome on item with `+1 and -1` and getting the resultant array. pretty much a combination of item taking `1` at a time or `2` at a time an so on.

I first thought permutation could solve this issue but its only gives samples : `[['+', '-'], ['-', '+']]` which is obvious.

I am not sure if this could be solved by applying a formula to get all sample space from probability.

What should I do programmatically in order to achieve the same this?

P.S.: The length of array can vary.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) method?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yep but that seems to solve only the part of it but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've edited your question, attempting to make it more clear.  It's a difficult question to state in words, isn't it?  I made many changes to the question; I hope I have improved it.  If I have not, please roll back my edit and accept my apology.

Comment: @WayneConrad Thank you for the edit. Actually I wanted to make it more general as in combination of item taking 'n' at a time and in between got confused. It's me who should be apologizing for not being able to put it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final edit: I have removed old code as it did not do what OP wanted.

Same code but keeping the order:

The idea of the code is to create an array of modifiers.

For the example with an array of size 3 and 1 elements that should be modified the first line of code would populate the variable `mod_final` with the array `[[-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, -1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`. Just a set of 1,0 and -1. Then in the final step we map this array and add it with the original to produce the final output.

```
array = [1,10,100]

def combination_plus_minus(array,number)

  # Create an array of modifiers we are going to use:
  mod =  [-1,1].repeated_combination(number).to_a
  # mod = [[-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, 1]]

  # Fill the rest of the array up with zeros:
  mod_with_fill = mod.map{|x| x + [0]*(array.size-number) }
  # mod_with_fill = [[-1, -1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]

  # Map each modifier set to every permuation, then combine them all:
  mod_final = mod_with_fill.flat_map{|x| x.permutation(array.size).to_a }.uniq
  # mod_final = [[-1, -1, 0], [-1, 0, -1], [0, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [1, -1, 0], [1, 0, -1], [0, -1, 1], [0, 1, -1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]


  #Finally take each set and add the numbers of the inital array: 
  mod_final.map{|x| x.zip(array).map{|x| x.reduce(:+) } }

end

p combination_plus_minus array, 2 #=> [[0, 9, 100], [0, 10, 99], [1, 9, 99], [0, 11, 100], [0, 10, 101], [2, 9, 100], [2, 10, 99], [1, 9, 101], [1, 11, 99], [2, 11, 100], [2, 10, 101], [1, 11, 101]]
```

If you are not happy with the order you can apply any sorting algoritm you want to the `mod_final` variable before it is combined with the original array.

Comment: But the things is adding or subtracting 1 can happen on may be 1 item at a time or 2 and so on up to the length of the array at a time. Here you are assuming that it's happening on all item and that is where I am also stuck. For ex: taking 1 item at a time should give the resultant array: [[2, 2, 100], [1, 3, 100], [1, 2, 101], [0, 2, 100], [1, 1, 100], [1, 2, 99]]

Comment: thanks for putting so much effort, actually your updated code does give the required element but just not in right order. for ex: when `+1` and `-1` on [1, 10, 100] taking 2 at a time should give: `[[2, 11, 100], [0, 9, 100], [2, 10, 101], [0, 10, 99], [1, 11, 101], [1, 9, 99], [2, 9, 100], [0, 9, 100], [2, 10, 99], [0, 10, 101], [1, 11, 99], [1, 9, 101]]`. Also, I really want to understand the details of your code, if you could please explain.

Comment: Tricky! This is a hard task. You should take a look at your underlying data structure and see if your design is really what it should be. What about my updated code?

Comment: Yep that works very well. thank you so much for the details.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of convoluted, but it should produce all possible permutations:

```
numbers = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

operations = [ :+, :- ].repeated_permutation(2).to_a

x = numbers.repeated_permutation(2).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).flat_map do |pair|
  operations.map do |op_pair|
    op_pair.each_with_index.map do |op, i|
      pair[i][0].send(op, pair[i][1])
    end
  end
end

puts x.to_a.inspect
# => [[2, 2], [2, 0], [0, 2], [0, 0], [2, 3], [2, -1], [0, 3], [0, -1], [2, 4], [2, -2], [0, 4], ... ]
```

This leans heavily on the `repeated_permutation` method to do the expanding. It also uses `send` to perform the math.

Comment: But in this case it is modifying the original array size. according to your expected the expected array is : `[[2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4], [0, 2, 3], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2]]` when applying `+1` and `-1` on each item of an array and returning the resultant array.

Comment: Hey I am so sorry I think the problem is in my question. let me update it.

Comment: You can change the `2` arguments to `3` if you prefer.

Comment: Yep I'll try that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is I want to do all possible operation(either + 1 or - 1) on each item of an array.

You can put all operations in one array and numbers in the second. Then you can iterate over them to cover all cases:

```
operations = %i(+ -)
data = [1, 2, 3]

data.each do |x|
  data.each do |y|
    operations.each do |operation|
      p "#{x} #{operation} #{y} = #{x.send(operation, y)}"
    end
  end
end
```

This script will produce the following output:

```
"1 + 1 = 2"
"1 - 1 = 0"
"1 + 2 = 3"
"1 - 2 = -1"
"1 + 3 = 4"
"1 - 3 = -2"
"2 + 1 = 3"
"2 - 1 = 1"
"2 + 2 = 4"
"2 - 2 = 0"
"2 + 3 = 5"
"2 - 3 = -1"
"3 + 1 = 4"
"3 - 1 = 2"
"3 + 2 = 5"
"3 - 2 = 1"
"3 + 3 = 6"
"3 - 3 = 0"
```

If you want to do operations against 1 and not against all elements from the input array, you can do it in the following way:

```
operations = %i(+ -)
data = [1, 2, 3]

data.each do |x|
  operations.each do |operation|
    p "#{x} #{operation} #{1} = #{x.send(operation, 1)}"
  end
end
```

which will give:

```
"1 + 1 = 2"
"1 - 1 = 0"
"2 + 1 = 3"
"2 - 1 = 1"
"3 + 1 = 4"
"3 - 1 = 2"
```

Comment: @Abhinay Okay. You can mark it as the answer if there is no further explanation needed.

Comment: is it possible to maintain the order and generate the result something like, if did `+1` on the first item then `[2, 2, 3]` similarly if `-1` then `[0, 2, 3,]` this is what I wanted to achieve. I am asking this because its the array which I was looking to generate on each operation.

Comment: Btw thank you so much for putting extra effort to provide detailed solution.

Comment: I don't understand "if did +1 on the first item then [2, 2, 3] similarly if -1 then [0, 2, 3,]". You mean to do it in the following order 1+1, 1+2, then 1+1, 1-2 and 1-1, 1+2 and 1-1, 1-2?

Comment: Don't forget about [`permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) and [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-combination).

Comment: I am sorry if its getting little confusing but what I meant is, applying these operations on an item of an array and then getting the resultant array. that is why I said if I add `1` to first item which is `1` in the example set the expected result is `[2, 2, 3]` and if I do `-1` on the same item then the expected result is `[0, 2, 3]` but thats OK I think now I have something solid to figure out the rest of it. thank you again.

Comment: @tadman thank you for suggestion, yeah I think in order to achieve the rest I should be using permutation.